# Isotope clickable element: Open only one div at the same time

Tags: jquery, jquery-isotope

For a Team-Page of a Company I will use Isotope with filtering by Position.
On click on an image the infos like phone-number, mail etc of that person should get visible.

That works pretty well, but now I have on question and I am stucked at one Point.
How can I only open one persons infobox at once?

For example:
I click picture one, the Infos shows up - then when I click picture two, person one should close so that only the infos of person two are open. Only one infobox at the same time.

Here is what I have so far, the complete code.
http://jsfiddle.net/qeMam/1/

and here is my code

```
// change size of clicked element
$container.find('.teamcontent').live('click', function() {
if ($(this).is('.large')) {
jQuery('.teaminfo', this).fadeToggle("fast", "linear");
$(this).toggleClass('large');
$container.isotope('reLayout');

} else {
jQuery('.large > .teaminfo'); 
$container.find('.large').removeClass('large');
jQuery('.teaminfo', this).fadeToggle("fast", "linear");
$(this).toggleClass('large');
$container.isotope('reLayout');
}
});
```

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

Every time you click one, you need to hide `teaminfo` and then show the one clicked:

```
// change size of clicked element
    $container.find('.teamcontent').live('click', function() {
        if ($(this).is('.large')) {

            jQuery('.teaminfo', this).fadeToggle("fast", "linear");
            $(this).toggleClass('large');
            $container.isotope('reLayout');

        } else {
            //*********** added this line *************
            jQuery('.teaminfo').hide();
            jQuery('.large > .teaminfo');
            $container.find('.large').removeClass('large');
            jQuery('.teaminfo', this).fadeToggle("fast", "linear");
            $(this).toggleClass('large');
            $container.isotope('reLayout');
        }
    });
```

see fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qeMam/2/

Comment: Wow, that was fast and it works like a charm!
Thank you very much!